# Trying to use KeyPress with arguments but don't know how to pass args correcly

Tags: c#, key, opentk, .net-standard-2.0, eventargs

I want the program to exit when I press Escape, the way it is right now, just close whenever a press anybutton.

Here is my code

```
game.KeyPress += (sender, e) => { game.Exit(); };
```

I using https://github.com/ppy/osuTK this as reference in my project.
Both KeyPress and KeyPressEventArgs Inherit from osuTK.Input

There is also this code bellow

```
Key.Escape
```

The Key also Inherit from osuTK.Input.

```
game.KeyPress<KeyPressEventArgs<Key.Escape>> += (sender, e) => { game.Exit(); };
```

This code above doesn't work, but something close to that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code according to [KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
game.KeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    if (eventArgs.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape) {
        // TODO
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

KeyPressEventArgs has the [KeyChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar?view=netframework-4.7.2) property. Use that to test what key was pressed:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me a .lot